# SpringRunner Integration Test Autowired is null

Tags: spring, springrunner

I am have a normal Spring Application (Not a Spring Boot )

When I am running the Integration Test using Spock , the dependent **dataUtils** Autowired is null

These are my classes

```
RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = AppConfig.class)
class DataProcessorTest extends Specification  {

def 'call '() {
    given:
      DataProcesser dataProcessor = new DataProcesser()
    when:
      dataProcessor.importData()
    then:
      assert  2 == 2
  }
}
```

Can anybody please let me know what could be the issue ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create `DataProcessor` object as normal object using `new`, not as bean.

`@Autowired` is a method of automatically injecting a bin into an object created as bin.

If you use `@Autowired` and `dataUtils` in `DataProcessor` is not null, you must create `DataProcessor` for bean, like below.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = AppConfig.class)
class DataProcessorTest extends Specification  {

@Autowired
DataProcessor dataProcessor;

def 'call '() {
    when:
      dataProcessor.importData()
    then:
      assert  2 == 2
  }
}
```

Here is a link for your reference.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire

Comment: It was a great help. , thank you very very much